# Looking for formulas to create a virtual binary tree from a simple list with an incremental index

Tags: data-structure

I have a task to make data structure like a binary tree (pic. 1).

[image: pic. 1]

Where each node has only two child nodes, for each node I should may get its nesting level, and for every two nodes, I can get the distance between them vertically. new nodes inserts into structure left to right from top to bottom for each level of structure. And for each node, I should get a level count that is filled level.

Can I create just a list of elements: 0,1,2,3,..,n (pic. 2), and for any index get his vertical level, number in the order in horizontal level through formulas?

[image: pic. 2]

If yes, what is the formulas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of nodes of each row of your tree is $2^d$ where d is the depth, and the first row is $d=0$. The number of nodes up to and including row $d$ is $2^{d+1}$. The inverse of $2^n$ is $\log_2 n$.

If you have node $n$ then its depth the smallest $d$ such that $2^{d+1} \le n$, which is $\lfloor \log_2 (n+1) \rfloor$. Using Python, your nodes 6 and 10 are at depths:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(math.log2(6+1))
2
>>> math.floor(math.log2(10+1))
3
```

and more programmatically:

```
>>> for i in range(15):
...   print(i, math.floor(math.log2(i+1)))
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 2
7 3
8 3
9 3
10 3
11 3
12 3
13 3
14 3
```

Another way to think about your nodes is via their binary representation, though in this case you should start from 1:

| i | i+1 | bin(i+1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0001 |
| 1 | 2 | 0010 |
| 2 | 3 | 0011 |
| 3 | 4 | 0100 |
| 4 | 5 | 0101 |
| 5 | 6 | 0110 |
| 6 | 7 | 0111 |
| 7 | 8 | 1000 |
| 8 | 9 | 1001 |
| 9 | 10 | 1010 |
| 10 | 11 | 1011 |
| 11 | 12 | 1100 |
| 12 | 13 | 1101 |
| 13 | 14 | 1110 |
| 14 | 15 | 1111 |

The depth is the position of the left-most '1' in the binary representation (That's what $\lfloor\log_2(n+1)\rfloor$ computes). Your node 9, for example, corresponding to the binary representation for 10, which i "1010". The left-most '1' is 3 positions to the left, so it's at depth 3.

Furthermore, the binary representation let lets you know how to find it: a "0" means go left and a "1" means go right. For example, the binary representation for your 13 is bin(13+1) = "1110". Start from the left-most "1". The rest of the pattern is "110". This means "right-right-left".

Go from the top of your tree (the 0), then right (on 2) then right (on 6) then left (on 13). Ta-da!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello! Can I get parent and child of each node by formula?